# Entity framework does not track record find by candidate key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I tried to find record using .Find() method and passed id as a parameter(which was candidate key into the database) but I was not able to find the record. I then used FirstOrDefault() method to get same the record. I got the record and then updated it and tried to save but EF was giving me an error like it doesn't have track of that record. Does that mean EF doesn't support candidate key for fetching record ?

Comment: You should add a minimal code example to your question.

Comment: And Paste your error

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question.

> Entity framework does not track record find by candidate key

And

> I tried to find record using .Find() method and passed id as a
>   parameter(which was candidate key into the database) but I was not
>   able to find the record

You need to read the documentation

[`DbSet<TEntity>.Find` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx)

> Finds an entity with the given **primary key** values. If an entity with
>   the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is
>   returned immediately without making a request to the store. Otherwise,
>   a request is made to the store for an entity with the given primary
>   key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the context and
>   returned. If no entity is found in the context or the store, then null
>   is returned.

No, `find()` cannot be used with any candidate key other then the tables primary key

**Update**

You can find records by any column (preferably an indexed one), you can update them without a problem, there is no limitation. any problem you are seeing in relation to saving records are not because of the situation you describe, ie candidate keys

Note that Entity framework **requires** a primary key in the mapping of the table (also if the table has not a primary key) to perform update or delete operations.

**Comment from David Browne**

> Technically EF does not require the table to have a Primary Key. EF
>   requires that the Entity has set of Key Attributes. These normally map
>   to the Primary Key in the database, but can map to **any key** you want

Comment: thanks Michael Randall. I had one scenario few days back where table didn't have any primary key and I couldn't convert that candidate key to primary key. So finally I dropped idea to go with EF and used ADO.NET to update that record.

Comment: @RaviMungalpara its unusual to want to create a table without a primary key or composite key, Also updated my answer

Comment: @RaviMungalpara You dont have to have an indexed column, it just makes sense.

Comment: @MichaelRandall i edited your answer: Entity framework requires a primary key in the mapping of the table (also if the table has not a primary key) to perform update or delete operations.

Comment: Technically EF does not require the table to have a Primary Key.  EF requires that the Entity has set of Key Attributes.  These normally map to the Primary Key in the database, but can map to any key you want.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for that, i have updated my answer